# Spark to pandas: np.nan is converted differently if Arrow is enabled

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-arrow

I noticed that NULL values in pandas (np.nan) are converted differently depending on whether or not Arrow is enabled. I was wondering whether this behaviour is intentional? If so, shouldn't this be documented somewhere?

Below is a simple example I used to reproduce my findings

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd 
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession 

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

df_pd = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "foo": [1, None],
        "bar": [2, np.nan],
    }
)

df = spark.createDataFrame(df_pd)
df.show()
// shows: 
+------+----+
|   foo| bar|
+------+----+
|   1.0| 2.0|
|   NaN| NaN|
+------+----+
```

However, if you enabled Arrow, e.g.

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.config(
    "spark.sql.execution.arrow.pyspark.enabled", "true"
).getOrCreate()
```

You get a different result:

```
+-----+----+
|  foo| bar|
+-----+----+
|  1.0| 2.0|
| null|null|
+-----+----+
```

To test, I was using a docker container (base image python:3.10-slim-bullseye) with following dependencies:

- Java: openjdk-17-jre-headless
- Spark: 3.4.1
- pandas: 1.5.3
- pyarrow: 11.0.0

Answer (score 0):

This is intentional. Arrow supports NULL, Pandas cast Nulls to "NaN"

This medium article explains in more detail. https://jorgecarleitao.medium.com/the-anatomy-of-the-arrow-format-9fff7efaece7